# Neurodevelopmental Disorders, Cognitive Function and Causing someone to Learn

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neuroscience, social-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience, learning

[Children may elicit, either through active engagement or some feature of their personality or appearance, a response from their environment that might protect them from deprivation-related risk either by reducing their exposure to risk factors or altering their impact once they have been exposed.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4130248/)

Could childern be caused by parenting, schooling and/or close social rings to learn neurodevelopmental disorders?

i.e Are parenting, schooling and/or close social rings able to cause someone young(Before the Age of 7) previously not suffering from the Neurodevelopmental Disorders or exacerbate them in those already suffering from them to learn those disorders by example or experience? Like one would learn table manners.

A parent with Neurodevelopmental Disorders will probably tolerate somethings that others would find problematic while being incommoded by something trivial to others. They will also focus on verbal communication. Speak verbosly, have trouble interpreting non-verbal communication.

If ones' parents have poor social interactions the offspring might not be that welcome. And thence develop their cognitive function accordingly.

If schools fail to notice early signs the disorder might progress further. Both due to lack of help and because teachers and classmates will drift away, bully, prank, hit, abuse.

Comment: We decided to start a discussion on [English Language and Usage SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/509345/12232) on whether or not using the phrase 'to teach a disorder', [used in the original formulation of this question](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/revisions/23843/1), conveys what the OP intends here.  Refer there if you want to participate in that discussion.